# Maintaining only predefined limited number of entries in objectbox

Tags: android, database, objectbox

I am using Objectbox db. I have a box for storing data.

I want limit the db size to 100 entries with first in first out basis.

For example if we put 101th entry, then the 1st entry should be deleted, so the db maintains maximum of 100 entries.

I know about live data model, but is there any alternative simple API, like `mybox.setLimit(100);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such functionality and there are no plans to provide it.

One way to do this is a [query with an offset](https://docs.objectbox.io/queries#limit-offset-and-pagination) of 100 and to delete the resulting objects.

Comment: Thank you for your response, also is there any way to observe only for db.count() changes, because now I am using observable, it is called whenever the same db item updated even no change on total count!

Comment: No, there are no count observables. Btw. if you want to see if there are "more than 100" entities, the fastest way to do this is `if(box.count(101) > 100)` (provide a maximum for count).

Comment: I already did the same, but I am using for download list, so whenever the download entries update (for ex: 4 downloads * 10 updates/sec for 30 mins)  it is called, so is there any performance degrade?

Comment: Version 2.2 caches `count()` results, so I guess it should not be an issue at all.

Answer (score 1):

While this feature isn't built into objectBox it's not horribly to implement. Give this a shot.

```
public void limitRecordCount(int max_records) {
    // Assuming mybox is a BoxStore object
    Box<Record> table = mybox.boxFor(Record.class);

    while (table.count() > max_records) {
        table.remove(table.query()
                .order(Record_.recordID)
                .build()
                .findFirst()
                .recordID());
    }
}
```